# ¿Como puedo consumir el API de Ubidots desde una Skill de Alexa?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy mandando lecturas de un sensor a la plataforma de Ubidots.

Lo que quiero hacer es consumir el API de ubidots con el ultimo valor recibido del sensor, desde una skill de Alexa.

Creo que el error lo tengo en la función que hace la llamada al API, el código es el siguiente.

```
function httpGetgral() {
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {

    var options = {
        host: 'things.ubidots.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/api/v1.6/devices/my-device/my-variable/values/?page_size=1&token=my-token',
        method: 'GET'
    };      

    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      let returnData = '';

      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        returnData += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
      });

      response.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
    request.end();
  }));
}
```

La llamada a esta función es:

```
var response = await httpGetgral();        
var rsp = response.results.value;
```

Si hago la petición desde el navegador, obtengo una respuesta.

```
"results": [{
   "timestamp": 1591155311893,
   "value": 35,
   "context": {},
   "created_at": 1591155311893
}]
```

No entiendo por que desde la skill no obtengo los datos, solo me dice; no encuentro la skill solicitada.

Por favor ayúdenme no encuentro como, muchas gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Por fin descrubri que es lo que paso, y por si a alguien le sirve.

La funcion funciona bien, el problema es que el API retorna un objeto en formato Int, y Alexa no procesa esta informacion.

lo unico que hice fue convertir el valor a String y funciona perfectamente !